# How to set the value of the additional field that not include in the text file data?

Tags: informix

I would like ask how to set the value of the additional field of the table ? For my project, i will load the text file data into the temp table but there is still have additional info like user_id, upload date is the additional field which is not include in the text field. May i know how to set the value of user_id and upload date?
Thanks.

Comment: Please can you describe your problem more clearly.  It would be helpful to include an outline schema of the tables, and maybe some sample data.  I am not able to understand from the existing description what your problem is.

Comment: For example : [supplier name], [invoice no], [invoice date], [do no]  , this 4 column data value load from text file and need to be insert into table_01. In the meanwhile, how can i insert the data that not coming from text file like [upload date] & [user id] into table_01? Assuming table_01 have total of 6 column data, how can i set the value of two column that not include in the text file in isql? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the information into the question, where you can format it properly.  Ideally, include a couple of representative lines — fake the names, number, dates, whatever, but have them look the same.  The square brackets, for example, probably don't exist in your data.  It looks like you might be playing with a CSV format.  Hopefully, "Messrs Peabody, Harcourt, Smith and Cromwell" don't figure in your data, but it would be as well to know what the format would be if a supplier name did include commas.